# How can I find the "best" or the cheapest location for the given network using excel

Tags: excel, function, networking

I have the following network in the image below:

Network

[image]

As you can see the answer is calculated and known. But, the answer was easy to calculate since there are only few numbers. Let me explain how this works. There are three locations A,B, and C. To travel from A to A, or B to B, or C to C, it costs $0 as seen in the prices given. Similarly, from A to B and from B to C, it costs $1000, and A to C costs $200. Then, the fixed prices are A = $20, B = C = $100. And the 999999 just represents that the path cannot be taken, which means that it must not be selected.

If, as in our case, only ONE location is required to be chosen, then all the letter and the letter combos with that letter at the end gets added together provided that it is cheapest, thus the "best" solution. However, all the ones with that letter at the end must be chosen. So, in our example, we have "C" as the chosen location because if you add all the letters and its combos for either "A" or "B", then you won't get less than $1300. Another condition is that, it must complete the path.

I hope that make sense. I want something in excel that can find that $1300 if I have a lot more numbers to input.

Comment: wouldn't the cheapest be A?  A+AB+AC+AA=1220?

Comment: If you choose A, then the letter "A" has to be the ending letter. Like I have "C" at the end or by itself in every variable(s) I am adding. The letter by itself must be included because that is the fixed cost. So, with "A" it should be A + AA = 20, but that's not a complete path. It is not doing anything.

Comment: Then why does BC get added to B making it greater than C?  If you only go by the last letter then B only = 1100

Comment: You are not involving "C", and you must. The problem I have is much more complex than this. In my problem I have to choose minimum of three locations. It is a little different, but same concept. Just saying.

Comment: see below.  You may need to refresh the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple SUMIFS() should work to find the cheapest route:

```
=MIN(SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & {"B","C"}&"*",4:4,"<>999999"))
```

Then an INDEX/MATCH to find the Location:

```
=INDEX({"B","C"},MATCH(MIN(SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & {"B","C"} & "*",4:4,"<>999999")),SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & {"B","C"} & "*",4:4,"<>999999"),0))
```

[image]

---

EDIT

To do what you want with formulas, on would need another table.  In one column list all the possible locations.

In a second column use this formula to find if it is a starting point only and no traffic flows to or through it:

```
=COUNTIFS($3:$3,"*" & A6,$4:$4,"<>999999")>2
```

[image]

Now we can modify the formulas from above slightly to refer to this new table and get the correct answers:

**These are now Array formulas:**

For the value of the cheapest route:

```
=MIN(IF(B6:B8,SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & IF(B6:B8,A6:A8)&"*",4:4,"<>999999"),999999))
```

For the name of the Cheapest location:

```
=INDEX(A6:A8,MATCH(MIN(IF(B6:B8,SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & IF(B6:B8,A6:A8)&"*",4:4,"<>999999"),999999)),SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & A6:A8 &"*",4:4,"<>999999"),0))
```

**Being array formulas they need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode instead of Enter. If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.**

[image]

---

Edit #2

Here are the formulas that work without the need for the helper columns:

```
 =MIN(IF(COUNTIFS($3:$3,"*" &{"A","B","C"},$4:$4,"<>999999")>2,SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & IF(COUNTIFS($3:$3,"*" & {"A","B","C"},$4:$4,"<>999999")>2,{"A","B","C"})&"*",4:4,"<>999999"),999999))
```

and

```
=INDEX({"A","B","C"},MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIFS($3:$3,"*" &{"A","B","C"},$4:$4,"<>999999")>2,SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & IF(COUNTIFS($3:$3,"*" & {"A","B","C"},$4:$4,"<>999999")>2,{"A","B","C"})&"*",4:4,"<>999999"),999999)),SUMIFS(4:4,3:3,"*" & {"A","B","C"} & "*",4:4,"<>999999"),0))
```

They are still array formulas and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Comment: But, we do not that it is going to be C before hand. We need to search it.

Comment: See edit @Bob.  If it works for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Could you tell me what those 4:4 and 3:3 are? And, are you pre-selecting B and C?

Comment: @Bob they are the full row references.  3:3 is row 3 and so on.

Comment: What if I have columns? Meaning that the data is transposed?

Comment: Then change the row references to columns. A:A for Column A and so on.

Comment: Ok. Let me try this with my problem.

Comment: Also, you never answered my question about pre-selecting B and C.

Comment: I am not pre-selecting, I am listing all the possible answers.  Since A cannot be an answer it was not included.

Comment: If you have more than the two just add them to the array.  Just make sure in the second one the arrays, the parts in the `{}`, are in the same order.

Comment: But, you are not supposed to know that A cannot be part of it. Excel is supposed to find that? Is it possible?

Comment: That will probably require vba.

Comment: Yea. I understand. Definitely for my problem. I knew this wasn't going to work. But, it was worth giving a shot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bob see edit, one last attempt before I head home for the long weekend.  You may need to refresh the screen.

Comment: I accepted it as an answer because it works for the problem that I have on here. However, it doesn't work for my original problem because it is much more complex as I said before. Thanks!